# knockoutjs checkbox property value does not change

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js

can anyone tell me why when clicking the checkbox, the checkbox does not get checked?

the simple code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/VTvYG/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observables are functions, so you should change

```
self.Selected = config;
```

to

```
self.Selected(config);
```

And for the checkbox, change

```
<input type="checkbox" />
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: AmISelected" />
```

Comment: Just one more thing... now when you click on the checkbox, the checkbox doesn't get checked, here is the updated version with your changes [link]http://jsfiddle.net/VTvYG/8/

Comment: `return true;` from your `SelectConfig` function to let the default action happen. http://jsfiddle.net/VTvYG/10/

Comment: As always, RP Niemeyer - awesome and helpful.